# Load all provider classes from a solution folder

Tags: c#

Given a .net application that supports different logic providers, how to instantiate one instance of each class in a solution folder? What is the way to iterate through all of the classes in the folder?

For example I have a folder in my solution called `MailClientProviders`
It contains Outlook and The Bat! provider classes that implement a IMailProvider interface.

In my App.xaml I call a Ninject container to initialize all the dependencies. Then I need to write a method that I would call, and would get an instance of each class returned.

```
heartbeatService.Providers = CreateOneInstanceOfAllClassesInProvidresDir(MailClientProviders);
```

What would be in the `CreateOneInstanceOfAllClassesInProvidresDir` method?

Comment: MEF seems more suited for this kind of job... AFAIK it can be combined/integrated with Ninject etc.

Comment: MEF seems like an overhead for a small app I have.

Comment: `MEF` is integrated in _.NET4_, I don't think it would be an overkill for your App. See [here](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guide&referringTitle=Documentation) for a guide, `MEF` is simple and does exactly what you need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used these functions to retrieve all classes in a folder implementing my custom interface:

```
public static List<T> GetFilePlugins<T>(string filename)
{
    List<T> ret = new List<T>();
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        Type typeT = typeof(T);
        Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);
        foreach (Type type in ass.GetTypes())
        {
            if (!type.IsClass || type.IsNotPublic) continue;
            if (typeT.IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                T plugin = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                ret.Add(plugin);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
public static List<T> GetDirectoryPlugins<T>(string dirname)
{
    List<T> ret = new List<T>();
    string[] dlls = Directory.GetFiles(dirname, "*.dll");
    foreach (string dll in dlls)
    {
        List<T> dll_plugins = GetFilePlugins<T>(Path.GetFullPath(dll));
        ret.AddRange(dll_plugins);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

So you can run `GetDirectoryPlugins<IMailProvider>` and use `Activator.CreateInstance` with every class found...

Answer (score 3):

[`Directory.GetFiles("MailClientProviders", "*.dll")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) to fetch all dlls inside the folder, then [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx) for each returned result and for each assembly [`Assembly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) to get all public types and for each type inspect if it implements the required interface and if it does [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) to instantiate it.