# Retrieve Objects That Implement Interface From Across Several Assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

I would like to retrieve an enumeration of instantiated classes that implement an interface from across several assemblies within a solution folder.

I have a the following folder structure (if this makes sense):

```
Solution
   -SolutionFolder
      - Project1
          - class implementing interface I would like to find
          - other classes

      - Project2
          - class implementing interface I would like to find
          - other classes

   -MainProject
      - classes where my code is running in which I would like to retrieve the list of classes
```

Therefore, if the interface being implemented is `ISettings`, then I would like an `IEnumerable<ISettings>` referencing instantiated objects of that interface.

So far, I have used reflection to retrieve the classes that implement the interface from a known class name:

```
IEnumerable<ISettings> configuration = 
                (from t in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CLASSNAME-THAT-IMPLEMENTs-INTERFACE-HERE)).GetTypes()
                 where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISettings)) && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                 select (ISettings)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
```

but this is a single assembly and I will not actually know the class names.

Can this be achieved using reflection or does it require something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I set the post build event of the each project in the solution folder to copy its assembly to the bin folder in the main projects bin folder.

The post build event was set similar to:

```
copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)MainProjectName\bin"
```

Then I used the following to retrieve the assembly file names from this bin directory (credit to Darin for his solution post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938860/load-all-provider-classes-from-a-solution-folder)):

```
string[] assemblyFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin"), "*.dll");
```

Then I retrieved implementations of the objects implementing the interface ISettings using:

```
IEnumerable<ISettings> configuration = assemblyFiles.Select(f => Assembly.LoadFrom(f))
                .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISettings)) && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
                .Select(t => (ISettings)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
```

This allows me to add further projects that implement settings without recompiling the main project.

Additionally, one alternative I looked at was to use `MEF` where an introduction can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VS2010TrainingCourse_IntroToMEF).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're only talking about Assemblies that are loaded into an AppDomain (which they'll have to be in order to do what you're after), you could use something like this to iterate through them:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain
         .GetAssemblies().ToList()
         .ForEach(a => /* Insert code to work with assembly here */);
```

Or if you have them loaded in a different AppDomain, you could use an instance in the place of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However, my assemblies won't be initially loaded into the app domain and I may need to plugin additional assemblies whilst avoiding recompiling the main project (something I didn't make clear in my original question I apologise).

Comment: You can use a combination of the code from your question, the code from my answer, and `Assembly.Load` at runtime to dynamically load the assemblies into your appdomain. Your plugins will only be executable if you load them anyway.